# Using Handlebars In ExpressJS: Layout Functionality

Tags: express, handlebars.js, pug

In **Pug** I can `extend` files to *follow* a certain `layout`.

Is this available in **Handlebars**?

And in general: what's the difference between using the `hbs` package and the `express-handlebars` package?

Thank you!